# Openh264 encoder increase number of IDR or I-frames

Tags: c++, h.264, openh264

I am looking for a way to control the frequency of IDR/I-Frames that openh264 encodes. Is there any encoder setting that can archive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int idrInterval = 0;
    m_encoder->SetOption(ENCODER_OPTION_IDR_INTERVAL, &idrInterval);
```

Did the trick!